# Como incrementar um valor à uma sessão?

Tags: php

Eu estou querendo adicionar um valor à uma sessão via GET. 
Estou fazendo desse jeito mas não funciona.

```
function addCart($product){         
  $cart['cart'][$product] = 0;
  $_SESSION[] = $cart;
}
```

Comment: Não funciona significa o que? que o item novo vai com um indíce númerico?

Comment: a variável `$cart` não está definida e causa erro, você precisa verificar se ela existe, e criar condições para caso exista ou não

Comment: Não funcionou. O que eu queria era armazenar os ids de um produto na sessão, ir incrementando eles a cada get.

Comment: Ryan, sugiro também dar um `name` para sua `$_SESSION[]`

Answer (score 1):

Exemplo:

```
function addCart($product){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $product;
}
```

Não se esqueça de utilizar o `session_start()`, pode ser até fora da função no início do corpo do documento PHP.

Referências:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-start.php
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259149/how-to-put-array-into-session
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: apesar na necessidade de iniciar a sessão, chamar a função `session_start()` dentro de outra função não parece uma boa ideia, se a função for chamada mais de uma vez ira causar erro.